# Compute points at a given geodesic distance on a mesh

Tags: graphics, geometry, mesh

Repeating [this](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/12485/17895) question for better visibility. I have a triangular mesh (assume a manifold mesh). I want to sample corners of a square on a mesh that is independent of the triangulation.

I am following these steps

- Sample a triangle (based on the areas of the triangles)
- Sample a point uniformly on the triangle/face
- Sample a pair of random perpendicular directions

I want to calculate the distance of three other corners of the square given an edge length. Since the corners can be on any other face, the output should be of the format (Face, barycentric coordinates on that face).

I am looking at libraries such as [Polyscope](https://polyscope.run/structures/surface_mesh/distance_quantities/) or [pygeodesic](https://pypi.org/project/pygeodesic/) that use the heat method to compute the geodesic distance between two vertices of the mesh, but I am not sure how to get points at an arbitrary geodesic distance from another point.

Comment: This isn't fully clear, what is "a square on a mesh" arbitrary meshes don;t have squares, do you mean the projection of an analytic square on some region or do you mean a set of 2 triangles forming a quad?

Comment: @Makogan - I don't mean a quad. What I want to do is get coordinates of the points on the mesh at distances of a, a sqrt(2), a in the directions 0, 45, 90 degrees respectively, assuming the initial point as origin and a random direction as one of the axes

Comment: Again, this isn;t super well defined, what do you mean by 0, 45 and 9 degrees on a mesh surface? You can define angles on a manifold of course, but you need to use differential operators and extend inner products for it.

It think we would have  much easier time helping you if you could draw a piture of what you are trying to accomplish.

I need to stress, euclidean properties don;t translate to manifolds. For example a triangle's angles do not add to 180 on a manifold necessarily.  And what a square is is not well defined.

Comment: Do you define a square by a shape with equal lengths or one with 4 right angles at geodesic itnersections? You can't have both in all manifolds.